# Windows 7 search doesn't find anything

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

The search bar feature in the Windows 7 Explorer doesn't work. When I'm in a folder with a file named "file.txt" and search for "file", it doesn't find anything. It never finds anything really. The search seems to work momentarily when I start rebuilding the search index in the Indexing Options window. Tried restarting the Windows Search service and running Microsoft Fix-it for to "Reset Windows Search", but it didn't help.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, people have experienced similar. Check out the "Related" column on the right and check through a few of those.

Comment: Similar question but looking for alternatives: http://superuser.com/questions/135423/whats-a-good-alternative-to-windows-search-for-files-and-folders

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reinstall the windows search components:

open control panel, go to programs and check "Turn Windows features  on or off " and uncheck the Windows search to remove it, restart and then add it from Windows features.

Meanwhile, confirm your search index location is include these locations files on.

Afterwards, go to Control Panel (icons view) > Index Options > Advanced > Rebuild.